# Real Analysis: proving basic properties from order properties of real number system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the order property:

$a \leq b \wedge c \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow a + c\leq b +c $.

Now, how do I prove that:

$a\le b \Rightarrow a \leq b + c \ \ \forall \ \ c \geq 0$

**Edit 1**:
If I had to show the general property of $a \leq b  \wedge c \leq d \Rightarrow a + c \leq b + d$, I'd have to add up the two equations but until now the order properties do not allow for any results to be drawn from that. They only allow multiplying(dividing) and adding(subtracting) on both sides.

**Edit 2**:
Starting with $a \leq b \wedge c \leq d$, I use transitive property for:

$a + c \leq b + c, c + b \leq d + b$

$\Rightarrow a +c \leq b +d$

Comment: What have you tried so far? This has nothing to do with [tag:soft-question] or [tag:real-analysis], please read the tag description to ensure the tags are appropriate to your question.

Comment: @AlexR, it's definitely Real Analysis, no?

Comment: Not even close...

Comment: Since $0 \leq c$ you get $b=b+0 \leq b+c$. Then $a \leq b \Rightarrow a \leq b \leq b+c$.

Comment: @Crostul, great. I also came up with something else from AlexR's suggestion. This is a simpler way that you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**: Show the slightly more general property

$$a\le b \wedge c\le d \Rightarrow a+c \le b+d$$

and apply a special case.
**Hint 2**: Use transitivity together with the property you have described:
$$a \le b \wedge b\le c \Rightarrow a\le c$$
**Hint 3**: Start by adding $a$ to the second inequality.

Comment: See EDIT1. Am I right?

Comment: Well yes, but that's not much at all. Try to put some thought into it; it's not too hard (note you most likely have transitivity as well: $a\le b \wedge b\le c \Rightarrow a\le c$).
NB: $=>$ can be made beautiful with `\Rightarrow`.

Comment: Done. Thanks. :D

Comment: @SPRajagopal Happy to help. Note that you missed the requirement $a\le b$ in the original question, I added it in for consistency.